# function to compare int input with another int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started to learn Python today and I hit to functions. I would like to compare the input if lower equal or higher than for example 5. It does not work correctly or I end up with invalid syntax

```
def functionX():
    fce = int(input('Enter number: '))
    if set('=<5'):
        print('equal or lower than 5')
    else:
        print('higher than 5')
functionX()
```

Output:

```
Enter number: 6
lower or equal to 5
```

Comment: Inspect line 3 of your code.

Comment: `if int(fce) <= 5:`?

Comment: Um, what is `if set('=<5')` suppose to do? Note, that is *always true*.... ie it is equivalent to `if True:`

Comment: `set()` creates, well, [a set](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set). You can try `a = set('=<5') ; print(a) ; print(bool(a))` to see, what your code did.

Comment: You created a set of those three characters.  Since the set is not empty, it evaluates as "truthy".  Look in your course materials to see how you compare two numeric values.  I'm voting to close for lack of expected research.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many cases where it is a good idea to use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) it is for use in lists.

In the example you gave above it seems you are not actually using lists so you don't need the `set()`.  Here it is rewritten without it:

```
def functionX():
    fce = int(input('Enter number: '))
    if fce<=5:
        print('equal or lower than 5')
    else:
        print('higher than 5')
functionX()
```